# Can anyone help me regarding trimming in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, trim

I am learning jQuery but I can't figure out how to use trim in jQuery.

```
// Cut trailing whitespaces 'foo bar    '

// cut leading nowhitespaces '    foo bar'

// now: put input back into inputfield.
inputField.val('foo bar');


// Check if inputField.val() contains regex.
// inputField.val() will give you a "string"

// if true - do something
```

Many thanks,

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: Lesson **#1** - it's **jQuery** - not "jquary" .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "   foo bar  ";
    str.trim();
    if (str.match(regex) 
    {
       ---do something---
    }
```